# Using GETDATE() and also adding time parameters such as between 9AM and 8:59AM

Tags: sql, getdate

I am trying to complete a query where I and looking at data from the previous day but I want to add a time frame such as `9 am (previous day)` to `8:59 am (current day)`.

I am using the code below that gets me the previous day data but I want to add the time.

```
AND [GasTime] BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE() -2, 102)  AND CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE() -1, 102)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What database are you using? I'm assuming SqlServer.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. GETDATE is a product specific function.

Answer (score 1):

If 2012+

```
and GasTime between format(GetDate()-2,'yyyy-MM-dd 09:00') and format(GetDate()-1,'yyyy-MM-dd 08:59:59')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use:

```
[GasTime] >= CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 2)) + CONVERT(TIME, '09:00') AND 
[GasTime] < CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() - 1)) + CONVERT(TIME, '09:00')
```

There is no need bounce between strings and date types.